# How do I revert renaming "unsigned long" to "unsigned long long" in "string.h" and other files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I made a mistake:

In VS2022, I wanted to rename all "unsigned long" to "unsigned long long" in my project.

However, I seem to have made it so that all occurances in all open files were replaced, also in "string".

How could I revert this? I have already closed and re-opened the project.
I actually don't even see where this string file is located.

I don't know where to find the original version of this file and where to put it, even if I had it.

I do have a backup of my own files, but not of the standard files.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Since standard headers are typically distributed with your compiler, probably better to uninstall and then reinstall your compiler and libraries.

Comment: Get your own files out of your  VCS. Get the MS files by re-installing the compiler.

Comment: Your image shows that you are able to open the file. Can't you just replace all occurrences of `unsigned long long` in that file with `unsigned long`? (Any occurrences that are supposed to be `unsigned long long` would have become `unsigned long long long` after the initial replace, so this would fix them.) Just trying to understand the problem -- the advice to re-install is good, in case you inadvertently made other changes.

Comment: @JaMiT Unfortunately I already "fixed" these errors, thinking I made a mistake.

Comment: How do I re-install the compiler? Uninstall and re-install VS 2022 preview?

Comment: @NeilButterworth What do you mean by "Get your own files out of your VCS"? My project files are on a different drive in a different folder.

Comment: @tmighty You should be using git or similar. If you make a bad change you can then get back the previous good version (or any other versions) very easily.

Comment: *"I wanted to rename all "unsigned long" to "unsigned long long" in my project"* Next time, I'd consider (naming apart) something like `using semantically_meaningful_name_type = std::int64_t;`. It should be more easily modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I revert this? I have already closed and re-opened the
> project.

That's the second mistake. :-(

If you recognize an error in a find-replace, just choose Edit->Undo, and everything is reverted. That works fine even in a multi-file replace.

Of course, once you close the project, the undo-info is lost, so you have to do it while the edit session is still active.